# "It is a matter of a long time back" - How to make it idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to say that the matter is very old but by using the phrase ***"a long time back".***

"It is a matter of a long time back" - How to make it idiomatic?

Comment: This sentence strikes me as a bit awkward, perhaps because it is so vague. I might say, "This happened a long time ago," but I'm having trouble imagining how I'd use "a long time back" with the word _matter_ as the subject. It doesn't sound as odd with something more concrete as the subject: _That meeting happened a long time back._

Comment: Sorry, would you please explain in an answer when to use ago and when to use back? why ago and back would make a difference here? @J.R.

Comment: @Aquarius - Both are grammatical but one is much more common. [Have a look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+long+time+back%2C+a+long+time+ago&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: To my ear, "it is a matter of" is not idiomatic, with time, and it's not clear what the OP wishes to say by it.  *It is a matter of the highest importance* is fine; but "it happened long ago" or "this took place long ago" or "it's ancient history" (figurative/hyperbole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest answer that sounds OK in English would be "It is a matter of a long time ago". This implies 100's of years. For older, you could say "It is a matter of ancient history". However, both of these phrasings are not in common spoken use, but could sound good in a literary piece.

Comment: i just wanted to imply 3 years back.

Comment: @Aquarius - Why not say, "This matter happened three years ago." Whether three years ago is a "long time" depends on context. If it's something trivial like an overdue library book, three years may seem like a long time back. For a more significant or cataclysmic event, though, three years might seem very recent.

Comment: We wouldn't really regard 3 years ago as 'very old' or refer to it as 'a long time ago' unless speaking to a child perhaps, for whom 3 years is a long time. In normal English. the phrase "...a few years ago" would work well.